# Is "nati sumus ut nutricati veritate" a grammatically correct Latin sentence to express "we born to be fed by truth"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Is "nati sumus ut nutricati veritate" a grammatically correct sentence in Latin language and does it express "we born to be fed by truth" or in a way "we born to be nourished by truth or /with truth or /of truth"? I am trying to create a Latin "motto" which contain "nutricati" or "nutricato" words inside it.

Comment: "nutricati (sumus)" will always mean "we were raised" or "fed" – that sounds weird in a purpose clause, in my opinion

Comment: So the correct unique translation would be "We born so that we were fed by truth" or also possibly "We born to (be) fed by truth"? And also is "veritate" ablative case used correctly, or should be used more properly another case? Thanks.

Comment: "We born so that we were fed by truth" is not grammatical English and it's difficult to know what is intended. Did you mean "we are born to be fed by truth"? Or "we were born so that we would be fed by truth"? Something else? Without knowing what meaning you intended a translation is impossible

Comment: Basically both "we are born to be fed by truth" and ""we were born so that we would be fed by truth" would fit. It is important by the way that the sentence contain  the term "nutricati" or "nuticato", so if the sentence is correct in latin I would like to know the correct translation. P.S. I apologize for my english.

Answer (score 11):

There's simply no way to make a grammatically correct sentence here that uses the specific form *nutricati* (much less *nutricato*), because for a sentence that contains a purpose clause, a perfect form (denoting simple past action) in the main clause can really be followed only by an imperfect subjunctive in the subordinate clause.

Therefore, if the motto has to use a form of the verb *nutricare* (which is not the most obvious verb to use, in my opinion), a correct sentence would be:

> *nati sumus ut veritate nutricaremur.*

Comment: I know that "nutricare" is an unusual verb, but it is essential for the "project".  Is it possible to avoid the problem you mentioned with a sentence like "we were born so that we would be fed by truth"? So to obtain a latin sentence with "nutricati" or "nutricato" word inside it?

Comment: @RickFeed 'We were born so that we would be fed by the truth' is already one way of translating it. As I said, you can't make a grammatically correct sentence with that meaning by using nutricati/nutricato.

Comment: @RickFeed I think that the only way to include *nutricati* would be to do something like *veritate nutricati sumus, quem ad finem nati eramus*, 'We have been fed by truth, for which purpose (or 'the purpose for which') we had been born.' It hardly has quite the same force as the English that you're trying to capture, or the Latin versions given above and in Sebastian's answer.

Comment: Indeed it seems a good solution.  Does exist a way to express the second part of the sentence (quem ad finem nati eramus) in a shorter way? Is "Veritate" ablative case the correct one to be used in this case?

Answer (score 11):

In addition to cnread's answer (which gives the usual way of expressing the thought), you may find it closer to your desired form *nutricati* to say:

> Nati sumus veritate **nutricandi.**

This means, roughly, "we were born as people who should/must be nourished by truth," which I think gets pretty close.

Comment: Indeed as you say the result is quite near to the objective. It lack the word "nutricati" or "nutricato" which is quite important eventhough. Is it possible to build a latin sentence that can match both the meaning (or at least close to it) and the required word? Thank you very much for the help.